# Execvp In Foreground

Tags: c, process, execvp

I am having trouble getting `execvp` to work similar to how `system()` works.

When I use the code:

```
int cstatus; /* Exit status of child. */
pid_t cpid; 
switch (cpid = fork ()) {
case -1:
    printf("fork");
case 0: // child
    system("./file");
            printf("child->");
default:
    pid_t tpid = wait(&cstatus);
            printf("parent\n");
}
```

The `./file` runs as expected and prints `child->parent`

But when I attempt to run the program with:

```
int cstatus; /* Exit status of child. */
pid_t cpid; 
switch (cpid = fork ()) {
case -1:
    printf("fork");
case 0: // child
    execvp("file", NULL);
            printf("child->");
default:
    pid_t tpid = wait(&cstatus);
            printf("parent\n");
}
```

I get an output of `child->parentparent` and the file does not show the output (generated from `file`) in the command prompt.

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm essentially trying to get `file` to run in the foreground and have the parent wait until it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in part that `execvp()` does not return except when it fails, but `system()` always returns.  So, `system()` is a replacement (cover function) for `fork + exec`.  You also need to consider whether the current directory is on your PATH.

Comment: I believe the PATH is the problem, because digging deeper into it I am getting _"File not found in directory"_ error. I'm just not exactly sure how to switch my path variable to my current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `break;` at the end of each case block.

And I overlooked that you're not providing incorrect arguments for execvp.

You need something like:

```
.
.
char *argv2[2];
.
.
case 0: // child
    argv2[0] = "file";
    argv2[1] = NULL;
    execvp("file", argv2);
    printf("child->");
    break;
.
.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. This issue is that `execvp` is not running in the foreground. I now believe it has to do with the PATH variable

Comment: I figured it out. It was the PATH, simply changing `file` to `../file` did the trick. Thank you though.

Comment: @Frank Interesting... in my machine, it complains about the second argument being null. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add "." to PATH enviroment variable, execute command `PATH=$PATH:.`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your directory is added to PATH environment variable by

```
echo $PATH
```

If the directory containing file is not listed in the `PATH` , then you have to add it by

```
PATH=$PATH:/myDirectory
```